# Issues get the bulk leads retrieval API to work

Tags: api, facebook, facebook-graph-api

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f79oU.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ROiq9.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eek24.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3eBVp.png)

Followed the format for bulk lead retrieval API for facebook but still unable get it, I already have the leads retrieval permission enabled as seen in the image

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.